# C++ Fastest way to find first space in right-padded null-terminated char array of fixed size 9

Tags: c++, string, templates, find

The average length is 4 characters for the strings.  I was thinking a binary search might be the fastest starting at position 4.  Also I think an inlined templatized function might perform well.  This is done in a very tight loop so performance is critical.

The data looks like:

```
"1234    "
"ABC     "
"A1235   "
"A1235kgo"
```

Comment: Are the chars sorted?  Otherwise, binary search won't work.

Comment: I think if the strings have size 9 you should not worry that much... anyway, you HAVE to check everything in order to find it, so a simple for should do it....

Comment: Is there a particular distribution pattern of spaces throughout the string?  Do they always appear at the end?  Are they always grouped together?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley no they are not however the spaces always appear at the end.

Comment: @chriskirk: Okay, then that is sorted, though not in the traditional sense.  It goes in order from non-spaces to spaces.  You can use a binary-search in this case, as per MSN's answer.  But for such a small dataset, the cost per check of a binary search may outweigh the cost of the few additional checks that might be done in a linear search.  Be sure you profile it if you are really concerned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
char* found = std::find(arr, arr+9, ' ');
```

Note that 'no match' is signaled wuth the end iterator:

```
bool match = (arr+9) != found;
```

Note, that

- binary search doesn't apply unless you characters are in *some known ordering*.
- std::find is *inlined, templatized* and will perform to the max if you turn on optimization (e.g. `-O3 -march=native` for g++)

**Edit** since you have shown more code, I now realize you actually want to detect (sub)string length. You could use

- [std::string::find_first_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/)
- [std::string::find_last_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/)
- std::string::find
- std::string::rfind
  etc.

Of course, that assumes you'd want to convert the char[] to std::string for the purpose. In practice, that might be a perfectly valid idea, because of SSO (Small String Optimization) found in nearly all implementations of the C++ standard library.
(see Items 13-16 in Herb Sutter's [More Exceptional C++](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mxc++.htm), or Scott Meyers' discussion of commercial std::string implementations in [Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629)).

Comment: I think checking pos 4 then 2 or 6 then 3 or 5, etc.. would result in less checks than std::find() since I suppose std::find starts at pos 0?

Comment: @chriskirk: yes, but you'll loose all the performance you think to gain by having to backtrack if it was actually in the first few chars. Also, branching instructions mitigate the CPU pipelining so you'll get nowhere near the performance of standard linear (SSE) string operations. _Of course, you can just try it out and profile, if you already think you know the answer... :)_

Comment: @chriskirk I think that's a lot of extra work for something so simple. If it takes 15 seconds to make your cup of coffee in the morning, is it really worth rearranging the kitchen to make it 13 seconds?

Comment: You can use binary search; the sequence is already sorted. Non-space characters come before space characters.

Comment: @sehe where can I read more about these standard linear (SSE) string ops?  I would have tended to think that the fewer the comparisons the better however I see your perspective on it.  So you agree std::find would be the fastest here?

Comment: @MSN correct, non-space characters will always come before space characters and there are always at least 1 non-space character.  Each char-array is also of size 9 where c[8] == '\0'

Comment: @chriskirk: I suggest you compile with `-O3 -g -march=native -s -o test.s test.cpp` to see the actual assembly code (test.s) generated. Also, profile, profile, profile. I'll update my asnwer though in a bit, since you added info

Comment: @sehe, no, non-space characters come before space characters, at least in this example. So it's more a matter of searching for where the runs of 1 starts in `000111111`, as an example. That is something you can definitely do a binary search for.

Comment: @MSN: (To be fair I did misunderstood your claim. 'other characters' in ASCII/UTF8 are usually > '\0x20', i.e. come _after_ space, if you see what I mean) I invite you to post the sample implementation of that, including the ordering predicate that you need for it work _and_ with a benchmark to see whether it is faster. For such small volumes, binary earch doesn't perform. _It is the same reason why library quicksorts are commonly optimized  to not use quicksort for small arrays, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Optimizations)_

Comment: @sehe, yeah, well, I didn't say it was a "good" idea, just that dismissing binary search isn't quite the right answer. SWAR should get you the right answer the fastest since this would all fit in 64-bits anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed use binary search to find the first space character (in this case using `std::lower_bound(...)`):

```
const char *data= ...;// 8 character string to search

const char *end= std::lower_bound(data, data + 8, ' ', [](char lhs, char rhs)
{
    bool lhs_is_space= lhs==' ';
    bool rhs_is_space= rhs==' ';

    return lhs_is_space < rhs_is_space;
});
```

Which is effectively using binary search to find the first space character. The basic idea is to pretend non-space characters are `false` and space characters are `true`, and to further assume that all non-space characters come before space characters. If this is true, then the sequence is sorted according to this classification and we can simply find the start (lower bound, that is) of the run of space characters.

Comment: @sehe characters are only A-Z,0-9 and space. Do you think this would be faster given the conditions?

Comment: Well assuming the text won't contain control characters (or if it's tabs, are considered trailing whitespace too), you could just say: `end = std::lower_bound(arr, arr+8, ' ', std::greater<char>())`. I base this, in part, on footnote [1] found on SGI's [lower_bound](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/lower_bound.html) page (_`Note that you may use an ordering that is a strict weak ordering but not a total ordering`_)

Comment: @chriskirk: I definitely don't think this will be faster. In fact, I anticipate this will be an order of magnitude slower, due to the small array sizes

Comment: I've never seen this syntax in C++ before. Is this C++11?

Comment: @Default, yes. That's a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Since the spaces are all at the end, you can use an unrolled binary search.  However, a regular linear search is *miraculously* close in speed, and won't make future developers hate you.

```
inline int find_space(char (&data)[9]) {
    if (data[3] == ' ') {
        if (data[1] == ' ') {
            if (data[0] == ' ')
                return 0;
            return 1;
        } else if (data[2] == ' ')
            return 2;
        return 3; 
    }
    if (data[5] == ' ') {
        if (data[4] == ' ')
            return 4;
        return 5;
    } else if (data[7] == ' ') {
        if (data[6] == ' ')
            return 6;
        return 7;
    } else if (data[8] == ' ')
        return 8;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to give you +1 for effort. It is pretty easy to see, though, that run time is going to be dominate by branching instructions, unless a very clever compiler optimizes it all away into... the equivalent of a linear character scan :)

Comment: Also, did you prove correctness? LOL. You make me want to test this. That's sad :)

Comment: @sehe: I did not validate my code, I'd be kinda surprised if there wasn't an error somewhere.  Even in a linear character scan, you're going to have `if char == ' ' then return`, so the branch is still there.  Though a linear probably pipelines better.

Answer (score 0):

Allow the compiler and optimizer to do its job.

```
inline
template <typename T_CHAR, int N>
T_CHAR* find_first_of(T_CHAR a[N], T_CHAR t)
{
    for (int ii = 0; ii < N; ++ii)
    {
        if (a[ii] == t) { return a+ii; }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Or allow the Standard Template Library authors to do all the heavy lifting for you.

```
inline
template <typename T_CHAR, int N>
T_CHAR* find_first_of(T_CHAR a[N], T_CHAR t)
{
    T_CHAR* ii = std::find(a, a+N, t);
    if (ii == a+N) return NULL;
    return ii;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents. I suppose all strings have length 8. Possible characters 'A'-'Z',
'a'-'z', '0'-'9' and space.
And I tried:

```
//simple
const char *found = std::find(x.data, x.data + 9, ' ');
//binary search
const char *end = std::lower_bound(x.data, x.data + 8, ' ', [](char lhs, char rhs) {
```

and my optimized version (it depends on compiler==gcc) (see bellow). 
I tested on Linux 64bit, with -O3 -march=native -std=c++0x.
Results for randomly generated 50000000 strings:

simple take 0.480000,
optimized take 0.120000,
binary search take 0.600000.

```
union FixedLenStr {
     unsigned char chars[8];
     uint32_t words[2];
     uint64_t  big_word;
};

static int space_finder(const char *str) 
{   
        FixedLenStr tmp;

        memcpy(tmp.chars, str, 8);

        tmp.big_word &= 0xF0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0ull;
        tmp.big_word >>= 4;
        tmp.big_word = (0x0707070707070707ull - tmp.big_word) * 26;
        tmp.big_word &= 0x8080808080808080ull;      

        return (__builtin_ffsll(tmp.big_word) >> 3) - 1;    
}
```