# Best C++ container for the following use case

Tags: c++, boost, stl, containers, c++17

I need a C++ container, either from **STL**, **Boost** library or which needs to be implemented, which best fits the following use cases:

- it is C++17 compliant
- it does not allow multiple elements with same value
- it has at least one element
- it has a fixed compile time maximum number of elements which is less than 10
- its elements are allowed to be unsorted
- it can be iterated
- elements are coming from a known pool of `constexpr` values

Please explicit **pro** and **cons** of each suggestion

Comment: a use case sample? what kind of value? why fixed size?
and, above all, what's your shot and why is not good enough?

Comment: Isn't `unordered_set` not good enough? Wrap it with size checking seems okay. Unless you have more detail use case.

Comment: Why not use a set or unordered set? Or even a map if you need key and value structure

Comment: @LouisGo @william_ `std::unordered_set` has unavoidable dynamic allocations under the hood

Comment: What's your platform? why do you need it to be fixed at compile time? Not sure if it's an XY problem.

Comment: @LouisGo I do not really need it to be fixed, but it is a property related to the elements I have to insert, they will never be more than 9, it should be possible to use this boundary to avoid any dynamic allocation altogether maybe. I need to add a boundary though, I'll edit my question. Platform is Linux, but I do not think it is relevant.

Comment: Federico and I were asking "why do you want to avoid any dynamic allocation"? There must be a reason which isn't described in your post. Please include the reason in edit.

Comment: @LouisGo Federico because they slow down the runtime, and if there is a chance to avoid them it is better to try to avoid them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The best solution I found so far is to use Boost Containers class named flat_set together with static_vector.

That's exactly what I'd suggest out of the box. Good job finding that - the AllocatorOrContainer style template parameters are a relatively new addiiton to the Boost Container library. Frankly, it rocks.

That said, I think you might find an unordered vector fast, due the very small sizes. In addition to the cache locality that flat_set already enjoys, linear search benefits more from RAM prefetch optimizations in the CPU pipeline.

See: [C++ Fastest way to find first space in right-padded null-terminated char array of fixed size 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043390/c-fastest-way-to-find-first-space-in-right-padded-null-terminated-char-array-o/8043419#8043419)

Of course, everything will depend on access patterns (what the `Element` type actually is, as well as what insertion/lookup patterns are used, whether duplicates are likely/unlikely etc.).

## Let's Profile It

Here's a side-by-side profile run that tries to do a decent coverage of data patterns to compare the averages. I added a custom `MyFlatSetImplementation` which uses `static_vector` as well, but **optionally** uses ordered/unordered storage. Note that is is also easy to add your invariants (such as the never-empty guarantee).

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/4EjM9T)**

```
#define NDEBUG
#include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>
#include <boost/container/static_vector.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
constexpr auto MAX_SIZE = 9;

template <typename Set> void run() {
    std::cout << "Static set size: " << sizeof(Set) << std::endl;
    for (auto v: { boost::container::static_vector<int, 20>
            { 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 7 },
            {},
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
            { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
        }) {
        while (std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()))
            Set(v.begin(), v.end());
    }
}

template <bool OrderedMode, typename T, size_t N, typename Cmp = std::less<T>, typename Store = boost::container::static_vector<T, N> >
struct MyFlatSetImpl : private Cmp /*EBO*/ {
    explicit MyFlatSetImpl(T element = {}) : _store(std::move(element)) {}
    template <typename It> inline MyFlatSetImpl(It f, It l) {
        while (f!=l) insert(*f++);
        assert_invariants();
    }

    inline auto begin()        { return _store.begin(); } 
    inline auto begin()  const { return _store.begin(); } 
    inline auto end()          { return _store.end();   } 
    inline auto end()    const { return _store.end();   } 

    inline auto size()  const  { return _store.size();  } 
    inline auto empty() const  { assert(size() >= 1); return false; } // invariant!

    template <typename T2>
    inline auto insert(T2&& v) {
        if constexpr (OrderedMode) {
            // FIXME could probably use just lower_bound/upper_bound
            auto er = std::equal_range(begin(), end(), v, getCmp());
            if (er.first == er.second) {
                return std::pair(_store.insert(er.first, std::forward<T2>(v)), true);
            }
            return std::pair(er.first, false);
        } else {
            auto it = std::find_if(begin(), end(), [&](auto&& el) { return getCmp()(v, el); });
            if (it == end()) {
                it = _store.insert(it, std::forward<T2>(v));
                return std::pair(it, true);
            }
            return std::pair(it, false);
        }

        assert_invariants();
    }

  private:
    inline void assert_invariants() {
        assert(size() >= 1);
        
        // dup check too expensive in unordered
        if constexpr (OrderedMode) {
            assert(std::is_sorted(begin(), end(), getCmp()));
            // no dups
            if (std::adjacent_find(begin(), end(), std::equal_to<T>{}) != end()) {
                std::cout << "Huh:";
                for (auto el : *this) {
                    std::cout << " " << el;
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;
                assert(false);
            }
        }
    }

    Store _store;
    // equal_to<T> for unordered, less<T> for ordered
    inline Cmp const& getCmp() { return static_cast<Cmp const&>(*this); }
};

template <typename T, size_t N, typename Cmp = std::equal_to<T> >
    using MyUnorderedSet = MyFlatSetImpl<false, T, N, Cmp>;
template <typename T, size_t N, typename Cmp = std::less<T> >
    using MyOrderedSet = MyFlatSetImpl<true, T, N, Cmp>;

int main() {
    using Element = int;
#if 1
    std::cout << "-------\nUsing STL set:" << std::endl;
    run<std::set<Element>>();

    std::cout << "-------\nUsing STL unordered_set:" << std::endl;
    run<std::unordered_set<Element>>();

    std::cout << "-------\nUsing Boost flat_set:" << std::endl;
    run<boost::container::flat_set<Element>>();

    {
        std::cout << "-------\nUsing Boost flat_set and static_vector:" << std::endl;
        using Container = boost::container::static_vector<Element, MAX_SIZE>;
        using Compare = std::less<Element>;
        using Set = boost::container::flat_set<Element, Compare, Container>;
        run<Set>();
    }
#endif

    std::cout << "-------\nJust unordered flat vector with constraints:" << std::endl;
    run<MyUnorderedSet<Element, MAX_SIZE>>();

    std::cout << "-------\nJust ordered flat vector with constraints:" << std::endl;
    run<MyOrderedSet<Element, MAX_SIZE>>();
}
```

Prints

```
-------
Using STL set:
Static set size: 48
-------
Using STL unordered_set:
Static set size: 56
-------
Using Boost flat_set:
Static set size: 24
-------
Using Boost flat_set and static_vector:
Static set size: 48
-------
Just unordered flat vector with constraints:
Static set size: 48
-------
Just ordered flat vector with constraints:
Static set size: 48
```

Notes:

- EBO (Empty Base class Optimization) makes for identical, minimal, size on this 64bit platform
- The asserts have been disabled using `NDEBUG`

Unsurprisingly, for `using Element = int` the linear search yields the better performance, taking ~34% less time than the ordered variation:

[image]

The ordered variation, unsurprisingly, has similar performance as your `flat_set+static_vector` combo (because it does roughly the same things):

[image]

### SUMMARY

Consider writing your own interface that improves performance by using linear search [due to small `n`].

This at once helps in adding the extra invariants your domain requires.

---

Comment: Very interesting and complete answer! I'll just have to try this code with my elements, which are a little bit bigger than `int`, and see which implementation performs better

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I found so far is to use Boost Containers class named `flat_set` together with `static_vector`.

- PROS: no dynamic allocation is ever performed
- CONS: it is still allowed to be empty (but that'd be nitpicking)

Code I run which compares different set implementations:

```
template<typename Set>
void run()
{
    std::cout << "Static set size: " << sizeof(Set) << std::endl;
    Set set = {1,2,1,4,5,7,2,4};

    for( auto element : set )
    {
        std::cout << element << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    using Element = int;
    {
        std::cout << "Using STL set:" << std::endl;     
        using Set = std::set<Element>;
        run<Set>();
    }
    std::cout << DIVIDER << std::endl;
    {
        std::cout << "Using STL unordered_set:" << std::endl;     
        using Set = std::unordered_set<Element>;
        run<Set>();
    }
    std::cout << DIVIDER << std::endl;
    {
        std::cout << "Using Boost flat_set:" << std::endl;
        using Set = boost::container::flat_set<Element>;
        run<Set>();
    }
    std::cout << DIVIDER << std::endl;
    {
        std::cout << "Using Boost flat_set and static_vector:" << std::endl;
        constexpr auto MAX_SIZE = 9;
        using Container = boost::container::static_vector<Element,MAX_SIZE>;
        using Compare = std::less<Element>;
        using Set = boost::container::flat_set<Element, Compare, Container>;
        run<Set>();        
    }
}
```

Output from GCC 10.1:

```
Using STL set:
Static set size: 48
new ptr: 0x2354e80 size: 40
new ptr: 0x2354eb0 size: 40
new ptr: 0x2354ee0 size: 40
new ptr: 0x2354f10 size: 40
new ptr: 0x2354f40 size: 40
1
2
4
5
7
delete ptr: 0x2354f40
delete ptr: 0x2354f10
delete ptr: 0x2354ee0
delete ptr: 0x2354eb0
delete ptr: 0x2354e80
=======================================
Using STL unordered_set:
Static set size: 56
new ptr: 0x2354f70 size: 88
new ptr: 0x2354fd0 size: 16
new ptr: 0x2354ff0 size: 16
new ptr: 0x2355010 size: 16
new ptr: 0x2355030 size: 16
new ptr: 0x2355050 size: 16
7
5
4
2
1
delete ptr: 0x2355050
delete ptr: 0x2355030
delete ptr: 0x2355010
delete ptr: 0x2354ff0
delete ptr: 0x2354fd0
delete ptr: 0x2354f70
=======================================
Using Boost flat_set:
Static set size: 24
new ptr: 0x2354e80 size: 32
1
2
4
5
7
delete ptr: 0x2354e80
=======================================
Using Boost flat_set and static_vector:
Static set size: 48
1
2
4
5
7
```